# Visual C++ Serial Out to Arduino

Tags: visual-c++, serial-port, arduino

I've come up with some code that reads character stats from a game. These values are stored in variables of data type `int`.

```
int HPvalue, MPvalue, TPvalue;
```

Now all I need to do is get these values out the `COM` serial port so they can be read by an Arduino.

I've found some serial examples online but it seems whenever I send my value more than one byte is sent.

I've some code running on an Arduino that reads the value from the serial port and turns an LED on or off depending upon that value.

When I send a value with the example serial code the LED toggles twice rather than switching to one state or another. When I send values with putty the Led responds correctly. that is to say. On for a value greater than 5 and off for a value 5 and below. This is what makes me think the computer is sending more than one byte at a time. Here is the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <atlstr.h>

using namespace std;

bool WriteComPort(CString PortSpecifier, CString data);


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD HPaddress = 0x046B670C;
    DWORD MPaddress = 0x043609B8;
    DWORD TPaddress = 0x043609BC;
    int HPvalue, MPvalue, TPvalue;

    DWORD pid;
    HWND hwnd;


    hwnd = FindWindow(NULL,L"EvelynofHades");
    if(!hwnd)
    {
        cout <<"Window not found!\n";
        cin.get();
    }
    else 
    {   
        cout <<"Found Window!\n";

        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&pid);
        cout << pid;

        HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, pid);


        if(!phandle)
        {
            cout <<"Could not get Handle!\n";
            cin.get();
        }
        else
        {

            while(1)
            {
                ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)HPaddress,&HPvalue,sizeof(HPvalue),0);
                ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)MPaddress,&MPvalue,sizeof(MPvalue),0);
                ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)TPaddress,&TPvalue,sizeof(TPvalue),0);
                cout << HPvalue << " " << MPvalue << " " << TPvalue << " " << "\n";
                CHAR on = 6;
                WriteComPort("COM3", on);
                Sleep(3000);
                CHAR off = 5;
                WriteComPort("COM3", off);
                Sleep(3000);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}


bool WriteComPort(CString PortSpecifier, CString data) 
{ 
    DCB dcb; 
    DWORD byteswritten; 
    HANDLE hPort = CreateFile(PortSpecifier, 
                              GENERIC_WRITE, 
                              0, 
                              NULL, 
                              OPEN_EXISTING, 
                              0, 
                              NULL 
                   ); 
    if (!GetCommState(hPort,&dcb)) 
        return false; 
    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600; //9600 Baud 
    dcb.ByteSize = 8; //8 data bits 
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY; //no parity 
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT; //1 stop 
    if (!SetCommState(hPort,&dcb)) 
        return false; 
    bool retVal = WriteFile(hPort,data,1,&byteswritten,NULL); 
    CloseHandle(hPort); //close the handle 
    return retVal; 
}
```

I may be implementing serial incorrectly for my application. Hopefully someone can help me straighten this out.

Comment: Have you debugged the output. What is going out from your code? You should also post the arduino code.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mistake is to open/close the port each time you want to write one byte:

each time you reopen the serial port, you restart your Arduino, and thus the LED gets off, and then you write your new byte, the arduino has waken up, reads the buffer and the led gets ON.

Open once your serial connection, keep the reference to the object file in your `_tmain()` function, and give it back to the `WriteComPort()` as a parameter to write/read things from it. And close nicely the serial port when you exit the `_tmain()` function.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Arduino platform. What makes you say that the Arduino restarts every time the PC software opens the serial port?

Comment: that's because it has been built that way! Though, it is not true for all arduinos (I think the atmega32u4 based ones are not subject to that). That way the arduino goes through the bootloader when you open the serial connection, and makes it possible for the arduino flasher (avr-dude) to upload a fresh new firmware.

Comment: Can the Arduino truly detect when the PC-side software opens the port? If it's true RS-232, I imagine it would take a custom driver loaded on that COM port. Even if it's a USB-to-RS232 chip (either on board or off), I'm not aware of any off the shelf ones whose vendor-supplied driver would enable that. If this is true, I'd be quite curious how the do it. It's all open-source, correct?

Comment: It's a hardware trick: cf [this document](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection): `The ATmega168 is reset by pulsing its reset pin to GND. The Arduino IDE itself cannot create such pulses, but by setting the DTR line to LOW and adding a capacitor (R3 on the pcb, marked red), the reset pin gets sucked to LOW until the capacitor is charged through the internal pull up resistor and R1 - which resets the chip.`

Comment: Interesting, certainly not what I would have done. Most (all?) FTDI chips have GPIO that seems like a better option to control the reset line. Anyway, thanks for the info.

Answer (score -2):

WriteFile is definitely going to write only one byte per call, and you can confirm that by looking at byteswritten after the call.

I wonder if you are writing what you intend to write, since CString is a strange choice of types to use when you seem to intend to write an int. Are you trying to send binary 6 (which you are) or the character '6' ?

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.